# Spring Boot setup with multiple authentication providers (API+Browser)

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot

My application serves both API and browser. I've implemented API Token authentication with all custom providers and filter. The configuration now seems to interfere with the browser version.

I have two questions that I need advice on how to solve, as I'm not getting anywhere after digging through the documentation and other examples.

1) My `StatelessAuthenticationFilter` is being called despite a request
coming from the browser. I have e.g. specified the request matcher to "/api/**". Why is that?

2) The `AuthenticationManager` have not registered two `AuthenticationProvider`s. This is my conclusion after debugging my `StatelessAuthenticationFilter` that's being called wrongly.

Here's the configuration classes that I have

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {


    @Order(1)
    @Configuration
    public static class A extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Autowired
        TokenAuthenticationProvider tokenAuthenticationProvider;

        @Autowired
        ApiEntryPoint apiEntryPoint;

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            StatelessAuthenticationFilter filter = new StatelessAuthenticationFilter();
            AntPathRequestMatcher requestMatcher = new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/**");
            filter.setRequiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher(requestMatcher);
            filter.setAuthenticationManager(super.authenticationManager());

            http.csrf().disable()
                    .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(apiEntryPoint)
                    .and()
                    .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                    .and()
                    .addFilterBefore(filter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.authenticationProvider(tokenAuthenticationProvider);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
            web.ignoring().antMatchers("/api/user/register");

        }
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class B extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.authenticationProvider(new DaoAuthenticationProvider());
        }    
    }    
}
```

As you can see, B class doesn't specify anything, yet when I access localhost:8080 the StatelessAuthenticationFilter is called. What is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

In class A you are configuring the StatelessAuthenticationFilter to use a requestMatcher. Whatever you do with that, spring does not know or care about that.
You must also restrict your security configuration using

```
  http.antMatcher("/api/**")
```

otherwise its configured for every URI and the StatelessAuthenticationFilter will be invoked for every request, exactly as you described.

You should also annotate class A and B with @Order as shown in the example at  [multiple-httpsecurity](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#multiple-httpsecurity)